# Split a region into segments based on majority points

Tags: python, clustering, spatial-cluster, segment

Having many points that belong to different classes (in the example below 9), I would like to split the region into multiple segments. In QGIS, the majority/minority tool does the job. In Python, however, I haven't find a way to do it. So far, I have tried with DBSCAN. Below is the image of the region covered with points that belong to 9 classes:
[image]

These are the points that belong to class 0:
[image]

It seems fairly simple to apply DBSCAN to group the points of class 0 to 2 clusters at the top and bottom, leaving out the points in the middle. With DBSCAN, however, I haven't managed to find the right parameter values to achieve it.

These are the points that belong to class 1:

[image]

In this case, grouping the points into clusters is even more complicated.

Given the fact that majority/minority filter in QGIS splits the region into segment that make sense. What kind of clustering or other method could be used to achieve the same result in Python?

Comment: Have you tried some [other algorithm](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html)